# Creating a Voroni diagram with arbitrary boundaries

Tags: computational-geometry

I have an image which I have segmented out points from which I would like to generate a Voronoi diagram from.

In the discrete space of the raster, there are some pixels occupied by "walls", which I would like to act as a barrier to the Voronoi diagram such that Voronoi cells grow as if there were no connection in space between the sides of the walls.

Currently the only way that I think to achieve this is to grow each Voronoi cell through brute force: take turns iterating through each point and grow the cell in a way similar to cellular automata.

I believe this to be a very poor solution as it does not scale well as the size of the raster increases. I am hoping that someone here knows a smart solution to this issue.

I believe I have presented a complete description of the problem, however it is likely that I am leaving out crucial details or definitions. I will update if I am made aware of problems with what I have asked.

Thank you for your time.

**Update:**
I have thought a little more and will attempt to modify the [jump flooding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_flooding_algorithm) in two ways:

1. if the pixel is colored with the boundary color, discard consideration for recoloring automatically
2. implement the A* algorithm for the dist() check which respects the artificial boundaries

Jumping flood is not a perfect Voronoi diagram - but in the context of what I am doing I believe approximate solutions to be more than adequate.

Answer (score 0):

The computation of the Voronoi diagram of a points set on a raster is very close to the computation of the distance map to those points. The only difference is that when in a distance map algorithm, whatever it is, you compare two distances and keep the shortest, in the corresponding Voronoi you will also note the identity of the closest point.

This said, this article describes an efficient method to compute 2D distance maps, including for the Euclidean distance. Up to you to augment it with the nearest point identities.

A. Meijster, J. B. T. M. Roerdink and W. H. Hesselink, A general algorithm for computing distance transforms in linear time. http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/S62.12/docs/Meijster_distance.pdf